# JSON pages only accessing the first page xcode

Tags: ios, json, nsmanagedobject

i am getting 10,000 records returned from a JSON query, and it is split into 102 pages with roughly 100 objects per page. The first 100 items are loaded fine, but then it stops loading more. How do I get it to go to the next page? How is this normally done?  This code used to be for sqlite alone. Now I have finished transforming it into a new app using core data, but it gets stuck in the first page.  Anything I am doing wrong?

here is the JSON nslog (last lines)

```
"PageNo":1,"TotalPages":102,"RecordCount":10163}




    -(void) serverDidFinishSending: (NSData *)responseData manager:(WebServiceCommunicator*)aManger requestURL:(NSURL *) url
        {
//Added the code below just to test out apple's JSON serializer
            NSError *error;
            NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"dictionary %@",dictionary);
            // Create the base object from factory.

//currently JSON serializer happens here 
    ReturnObjectFactory *aFactory = [[[ReturnObjectFactory alloc] init] autorelease];
        id object = [aFactory createObjectWithClassName:_className fromData:responseData];

        // Pass on the object to the target class and let that class deal with this object
        if(_target && [_target respondsToSelector:@selector(didRecieveObject:sender:)])
           [_target didRecieveObject:object sender:self];
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you please post Some code what you have already tried  ?

Comment: Did you get any chance to try my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Think you are getting a Array of Dictionary so when you firing your query , you are getting only first index of array. So try to get all data by creating a loop.

Try the below Code.

```
-(void) serverDidFinishSending: (NSData *)responseData manager:(WebServiceCommunicator*)aManger requestURL:(NSURL *) url
{
NSError *error;
id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"dictionary %@",jsonObject);

if ([jsonObject respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)])
     {
// This is a dictionary
// Create the base object from factory.
ReturnObjectFactory *aFactory = [[[ReturnObjectFactory alloc] init] autorelease];
// get your stuffs here
    }
else
    {
    // Treat as a Array
    }

}
```

Comment: Did not seem to loop. So if the nslog is telling me 102 pages. Does that mean 102 dictionaries?  How do I loop to the next page?

Comment: Put your API link in Browser , Then you will get the Response in JSON then copy all and Paste here: http://json.bloople.net   You can get a clear idea on Structure and Easily can get all data.